# How to run multiple instances of one app in linux?

Tags: permissions, users

I want to run multiple instances of Viber on Linux.
I used Sandboxie on Windows and it was very easy, I could create multiple profiles for multiple accounts. But on Linux I cant find an alternative with easy GUI. Can I do it somehow?

Comment: Maybe [Kasm worksapces](https://www.kasmweb.com/) should do it, I've never used it but it looks like should be useful in this case.

Comment: Hi! Welcome here! What's Viber? Generally, isolation of processes is very easy on Linux, you might not even need any additional tools your system doesn't already come with. But that depends on: 1. What kind of software Viber is, 2. What your Linux distro is. Please tell us!

Comment: (and maybe tell us how you installed Viber, too!)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.